# Update Data into table from another table using SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssdt-bi

How to update data from one table to another table where A common column value matched (both tables are on different server) , Can we design a SSIS package for such case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can link the server using

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver [ @server= ] 'server' [ , [ @srvproduct= ] 'product_name' ]   
 [ , [ @provider= ] 'provider_name' ]  
 [ , [ @datasrc= ] 'data_source' ]   
 [ , [ @location= ] 'location' ]   
 [ , [ @provstr= ] 'provider_string' ]   
 [ , [ @catalog= ] 'catalog' ]
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx

and then

```
select * from [server].[database].[schema].[table]
```